# JavaScript: Dynamically Creating Variables for Loops

Tags: javascript

How can I use a for loop to dynamically create variables, and be returned.

```
function createVariables()
{
for ( i=0; i<=20; i++ )
    {
        var account = i;
        return var account + i;
    }
 }
```

The goal is to have the result below:

```
var account1;
var account2;
var account3; and etc.....
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You should use an array:

```
function createVariables(){
  var accounts = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
      accounts[i] = "whatever";
  }

  return accounts;
}
```

You then have access to `accounts[0]` through `accounts[20]`.

Comment: idea is to create variables with the strings we have...
e.g., I have array var arr = ['myOwnName'];
and from this create a variable called , var myOwnName;

Comment: You cannot create dynamically new variables, but you might consider using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for this purpose

Answer (score 27):

The only way I know how to do this would be to use the JavaScript `eval` function.

Something like `eval("account" + 1 + "='some value'");`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

However, I think @Domenic has a better answer.

Comment: His answer only is good if you know what variables you will need.

Answer (score 11):

I was unsure about [answering an old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20524/reviving-old-questions) however I stumbled across this while seeking an answer myself.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) { // Creating 10 objects
window["Object"+i] = new Object();
}
console.log(Object7); // is not undefined
```

The above code loops to 10 while creating dynamic objects, as described on https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/51068e93f73ad4947a005629

Comment: Absolutely much better than `eval()` recommandation above. Thanks!

Comment: absolutely not better, node.js doesn't know what window is. Question is about js, nowhere is specified that this only should work in a browser

Answer (score 8):

I find this a simplest solution

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   this["RONAK"+i] = "MY VAL";
}
```

**Output**

```
RONAK0 = "MY VAL"
RONAK1 = "MY VAL"
RONAK2 = "MY VAL"
...
RONAK9 = "MY VAL"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the eval() method to declare dynamic variables as it executes JavaScript statements passed to it.

```
function createVariables()
{
    for ( i=0; i<=20; i++ )
    {
        var str ="account"+ i+" = undefined";
        //Declaring and Setting dynamic variable to undefined using eval
        eval(str);
    }
}
createVariables();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let etc = { name: 'foobar', city: 'xyz', company: 'companyName' };

Object.keys(etc).forEach(key=>{
window[`${key.toUpperCase()}`] = new Object(`${etc[`${key}`]}`)
});

console.log("-->"+NAME) //foobar
```

this is similar to what [@whatevermike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5127350/whatevermike) describes but it does not work in NodeJS because it uses window. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
function createVariables() {
    var accounts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
        accounts[i] = "merhaba" + i;
    }
    return accounts;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add an explanation along with your code, so that OP and others can better understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will actually create variables, instead of creating this sort of hash table proposed by @Domenic

```js
    function createVariables(){
        var varName = "accounts";

        for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
            eval('var ' + varName + i + ' = ' + '"whatever"' + ';');
        }

        return accounts;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty proud of the way I made iterating variables with my code, was going to share it but I think I'll just sort of show you modified version of it.

```
function variableBuilder() {
   let i = 0;
   while (i <= 20) {
      let accountVariable = "account".concat(i);
      `// variable can even be reassigned here`
      console.log(accountVariable);
      i++;
   }
}
```

you can use the variable as an iterating variable identifier, in the spot that I suggested; I used this method to build DOM nodes, to create a dynamically built HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

we can use map for it.

```
var map = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  map["nutrient" + i] = "some stuff" + i;
}
console.log(map)
```

result:

```
{
  nutrient0: 'some stuff0',
  nutrient1: 'some stuff1',
  nutrient2: 'some stuff2',
  nutrient3: 'some stuff3',
  nutrient4: 'some stuff4',
  nutrient5: 'some stuff5',
  nutrient6: 'some stuff6',
  nutrient7: 'some stuff7',
  nutrient8: 'some stuff8',
  nutrient9: 'some stuff9'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest method is to use eval and write the variable declaration line inside a loop that follows your conditions

```
    for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
          eval(`var variable${i}=${i}`);
          eval(`console.log(variable${i})`)
      }
//Output:
0
1
2
3
```

You can also console log the values outside as they are declared global with the **var** keyword