# create names for automatically created vars

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript I have a `for` snippet to create new input elements

```
for(var g = 0; g < psi.length; g++) {
var newtextLink+(g+1)= document.createElement('input');
//continue with setting attributes
}
```

I want to put together the word `newtextLink` and the var `g` to have something like `newtextLink2` everytime `for` is executed...How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is where you usually want an array instead:

```
var newtextLinks = [];
for(var g = 0; g < psi.length; g++)
{
    newtextLinks[g] = document.createElement('input');
}
```

Then use them via index variables like that (`newtextLink[g]`, `newtextLink[0]`, etc.).

Alternately, there can be places (probably not here) where you really do want *names*. You can do that with an object:

```
var newtextLinks = {};
for(var g = 0; g < psi.length; g++)
{
    newtextLinks["name" + (g+1)] = document.createElement('input');
}
```

Now you have `newtextLinks.name1`, `newtextLinks.name2`, and so on.

But for this purpose, an array seems best.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the variables, you can do it using the `window` object:

```
window['newtextLink' + (g+1)] = document.createElement('input');
```

Otherwise use an array:

```
var newTextLinks = [];

...

newTextLinks[g] = document.createElement('input');
```

Comment: You can't use this for a local variable

Comment: And creating more global variables is usually not a good idea. (Oh, I see you've added the array option now...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I realise now that people new to arrays usually look for a solution like that, I guess I took the question a bit too literally.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this['newtextLink' + (g + 1)] = ...;
```

Comment: That will either pollute the global namespace, or pollute some other object. Neither is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createVariables(){
  var newtextLink= [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= psi.length; ++i) {
      newtextLink[i] = document.createElement('input');
  }

  return newtextLink;
}
```

you have newtextLink[0] ... newtextLink[n]

you have similar question here:
[JavaScript: Dynamically Creating Variables for Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645067/javascript-dynamically-creating-variables-for-loops)