# Merging two variable names together in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to make a loop in which I create multiple markers for Google Maps. I want these markers to be named marker+int. I can't merge 2 variable names as I found out, so I need another way to do this. Can anyone help me out? I don't have an array to loop through...

```
var counter = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    counter++;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng, 
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shadow: shadow,
        title: label
    }); 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Dynamically Creating Variables for Loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645067/javascript-dynamically-creating-variables-for-loops)

Answer (score 3):

What about to define `array` and iterate though it like:

```
var marker = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++ ) {
    marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng, 
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shadow: shadow,
        title: label
    }); 
}
```

You can output result from `marker` `array` simple just like

```
for ( var j = 0; j < marker.length; j++ ) { // output all the information from marker array
    console.log(marker[j].position);
    console.log(marker[j].map);
    console.log(marker[j].icon);
    console.log(marker[j].shadow);
    console.log(marker[j].title);
}
```

**NOTE:** `counter` variable isn't needed as you already have counter which is represented by `i` variable inside the loop

Comment: Your answer is constructing an array. But I also have to loop through it to actually have these markers appear in gmaps, right?

Comment: @FrankKluytmans Due to retrieve information from array Yes, you have to make another loop for it

Comment: @FrankKluytmans: I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object) to learn how to work with them.

Comment: I understand arrays quite well I think. Looping is not the problem. But how do I output all the markers in the loop? I don't want to log them but actually have them shown on the map...

Answer (score 0):

You an object or an array

```
var markers = [];
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    markers[i] = "Hello";
}
```

If you want to have names, than use an object

```
var obj = {};
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    obj["marker" + i] = "Hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put all maker in an Object.

```
var myObject = [];   
myObject.push(marker);
```