# Dynamic name for JS variable

Tags: javascript

Can you please guide me how to replace a long javascript with a loop or something similar? I've to create some variables and after that call a method after each key press.

```
var list1 = new List('list1', options);
var list2 = new List('list2', options);
var list3 = new List('list3', options);
var list4 = new List('list4', options);
var list5 = new List('list5', options);
var list6 = new List('list6', options);
var list7 = new List('list7', options);
var list8 = new List('list8', options);
var list9 = new List('list9', options);
var list10 = new List('list10', options);
var list11 = new List('list11', options);

$('.search-field').on('keyup', function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    list1.search($(this).val());
    list2.search($(this).val());
    list3.search($(this).val());
    list4.search($(this).val());
    list5.search($(this).val());
    list6.search($(this).val());
    list7.search($(this).val());
    list8.search($(this).val());
    list9.search($(this).val());
    list10.search($(this).val());
    list11.search($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: You should be able to find a tutorial on how to work with a `for` loop pretty easily. And you may also want to check a tutorial on `Array`s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create dynamic variable names inside a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260156/how-do-i-create-dynamic-variable-names-inside-a-loop)

Comment: Another duplicate [JavaScript: Dynamically Creating Variables for Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645067/javascript-dynamically-creating-variables-for-loops)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Dynamically Creating Variables for Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645067/javascript-dynamically-creating-variables-for-loops)

Answer (score 2):

You can group your variables as array or object.

For example (variables in object):

```
const n = 11;
var lists = {};

for(let i=1;i<=n;++i) {
    lists['list'+i] = new List('list'+i, options);
}

$('.search-field').on('keyup', function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    for(let i=1;i<=n;++i) {
        lists['list'+i].search($(this).val());
    }
}
```

Where object key is "variable name" and value for that key is just value

```
object[key] = value // write value
object[key]         // read value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code with this. Start with an empty `array`. Then use a `for` loop to add elements, then use another `for` loop to call function

```
const list = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  list[i] = new List('list' + i, options);
}


$('.search-field').on('keyup', function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    list[i].search($(this).val());
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution but I don't know why it is not working, when I replace it with the original code I wrote above it is working again!