# Assigning multiple variables containing jquery selectors faster with for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I reduce the below code? I want to assign multiple variables in  fewer lines, perhaps a for loop could help.

```
let a1 = $('[name="answer[1]"]:checked').val(),
    a2 = $('[name="answer[2]"]:checked').val(),
    a3 = $('[name="answer[3]"]:checked').val(),
    a4 = $('[name="answer[4]"]:checked').val(),
    a5 = $('[name="answer[5]"]:checked').val(),
    a6 = $('[name="answer[6]"]:checked').val(),
    a7 = $('[name="answer[7]"]:checked').val();
```

What I have tried but not working:

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    let a[i] = $('[name="answer['+i+']"]:checked').val();
}
```

Comment: Is this for JS in a browser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645067/javascript-dynamically-creating-variables-for-loops I think this will answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Dynamically Creating Variables for Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645067/javascript-dynamically-creating-variables-for-loops)

Comment: My question contains variables with jquery selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a browser environment, you can assign variables by setting a property of the `window` object:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  window["a"+i] = "something "+i;
}

console.log(a2, a3);
```

As for your code, use this:

```
window["a"+i] = $('[name="answer['+i+']"]:checked').val();
```

In the `for` loop

Comment: Can you put an answer looping this `$('[name="answer[1]"]:checked').val()` ?

Comment: I added an example for this.

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is this

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) { 
  let a[i] = $('[name="answer['+i+']"]:checked').val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
      a[i] = "whatever";
  }
```

as posted in
 [JavaScript: Dynamically Creating Variables for Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645067/javascript-dynamically-creating-variables-for-loops)