# How do i get the kahootbot to join multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, node-modules

I have this code here:

```
var Kahoot = require("kahoot.js-updated");
var client = new Kahoot;
console.log("Joining kahoot...");
client.join(9802345 /* Or any other kahoot game pin */, "kahoot.js");
client.on("joined", () => {
    console.log("I joined the Kahoot!");
});
client.on("quizStart", quiz => {
    console.log("The quiz has started! The quiz's name is:", quiz.name);
});
client.on("questionStart", question => {
    console.log("A new question has started, answering the first answer.");
    question.answer(0);
});
client.on("quizEnd", () => {
    console.log("The quiz has ended.");
});
```

And i want to know how to get the bot to join the kahoot multiple times.

I have already tried adding `client.setMaxListeners(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)` which solves the error with too many listeners. I tried using `setInterval()`
for the join command but it just says Joining kahoot... and never connects.

How would I get the kahootbot to join said kahoot multiple times? (like 100 times or so)

Comment: You need one client per player for this library.

Comment: thank you for that answer, I literally got an upvote but no answer lol

Comment: For future reference, it's a lot easier for us if you're using an unofficial library to specify which one you're using in your question.

Comment: could i do something like
var num = 0;
num++;

setInterval(function() {
var (client + num) = new Kahoot;
}, 30)

or something

Comment: Mmm well if you want to periodically create them... although you could do a simple for loop and add them to an array if you want a fixed number of players.

Comment: i wanted to know how exactly to make it so that it can make a bunch of clients without me having to put it all the clients myself

Comment: Do you need a random number? A fixed number?

Comment: a random number at the end of each client, like client1, client2, etc

Comment: It sounds like you want to dynamically generate variables. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645067/javascript-dynamically-creating-variables-for-loops). As that answer suggests, you almost never need to create the actual variables (e.g. client1, client2, etc), because you can use an array.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i <= 400; ++i) {
        clients[i] = new Kahoot;
        clients[i].setMaxListeners(10000);
        clients[i].join(3749 /* Or any other kahoot game pin */, "kahoot.js" + i);
}
?

Comment: Yeah, that looks like it should work. Perhaps the setMaxListeners might be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Code to join a new bot every 300ms:

```
const Kahoot = require("kahoot.js-updated");


setInterval(kahoot, 300)
function kahoot() {
const client = new Kahoot;
var name = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999).toString()

client.join(2676002, name);

client.on("Joined", () => {
  console.log("I joined the Kahoot!");
}); 

client.on("QuizStart", () => {
}); 

client.on("QuestionStart", question => {
  question.answer(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));
  console.log('i answered a question') 
});
client.on("QuizEnd", () => {
  console.log("The quiz has ended.");
}); 

}
```

The kahoot client is being created as a local variable in a function, kahoot(), being called every 300ms. This means that a new bot will be created every 300ms. These bots will also answer questions with a random answer.