# Defining a variable using template strings

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6, template-strings

Is it possible to create a variable using template strings? Here is a simple example of what I want to achieve:

```
    let times, hours="fullTime";

    if (hours === "fullTime") {
        times = ["Day", "Night"];
      } else {
        times = ["Day"];
      }

      times.forEach((time) => {
        const `${time}shift` = "8 hours";
      }

      console.log(DayShift);
```

log: "8 hours"

I want a new variable with a different name to be defined everytime that forEach loop iterates.

Thanks

Comment: For global variable, you can use `window[time+"shift"] = "8 hours";`. But you'd probably be better off setting that within a better-scoped JSON object property rather than on the `window` object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Dynamically Creating Variables for Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645067/javascript-dynamically-creating-variables-for-loops)

Answer (score 3):

Of course, just store them in an object. Simply add keys to the object.

```js
let times, hours = "fullTime";

if (hours === "fullTime") {
  times = ["Day", "Night"];
} else {
  times = ["Day"];
}

let variables = {};

times.forEach((time) => {
  variables[`${time}shift`] = "8 hours";
});

console.log(variables);
console.log(variables.Dayshift);
```