# How do you dynamically create unpacked variable names using destructuring syntax in JS ES6?

Tags: arrays, variables, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Observe the following:

```
let gamesArray = ['Shadow of the Beast 2', 'Flashback', 'Turricain 2', 'Gods', 'Speedball 2', 'First Samurai', 'Beneath a steal sky', 'Magic Pockets', 'Superfrog', 'Final Fight'];
let [Game_1, Game_2, Game_3, Game_4, Game_5, Game_6, Game_7, Game_8, Game_9, Game_10] = gamesArray;

console.log(Game_8); // Magic Pockets
console.log("\n");
```

I was wondering that if we were unpacking 10 array elements as separate variables and wanted to call them Game_[an incremented number] how would we go about it ? I was trying a few things by running the code in Atom text editor with JS enabled.

obviously a small array is easy to unpack and refer back to as opposed to an array with ten elements as seen in the above example.

Anybody got any ideas ?

Comment: i.e instead of manually typing the variable names 'Game_1, Game_2'  wouldn't it be better to use a for-of loop and then dynamically create each variable name ?

Comment: No, this is not possible, and it makes no sense to use dynamic variable names. Just `console.log(gamesArray[8])`!

Comment: In JS, the variables are static. You have to use objects (e.g. arrays) to have dynamic keys.

Comment: Duplicate of [JavaScript: Dynamically Creating Variables for Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645067/javascript-dynamically-creating-variables-for-loops)

Comment: Thanks for notifying us all @ FZs
This helped me somewhat, geekforgeeks..

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript/

I was already trying something similar and almost did it in a bespoke way without geek4geeks link.