# Looping Javascript Array Objects and Separate Objects With Condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have a variable named data

```
const data = [
        {loanname: "Mr X", acnumber:  "020000000000001", outstanding: "54000"},
        {loanname: "Mrs Y", acnumber: "020000000000087", outstanding: "87000"},
        {loanname: "Mr Z", acnumber:  "020000000000103", outstanding: "15000"},
        {totalaccount: "3", outstanding: "156000"},
        {loanname: "David", acnumber: "020000000000091", outstanding: "11000"},
        {loanname: "James", acnumber: "020000000001291", outstanding: "4000"},
        {totalaccount: "2", outstanding: "15000"},

    ]
```

It's an array. I would like to extract data items depending on how many times there are totalaccount. For example, before the first totalaccount, there are three accounts. I would like to extract them.

Also, before the last totalaccount, there are two accounts if we can skip the first totalaccount. I would like to extract information for those two accounts.

To be more precise, how can I convert the array into the following?:

```
let firstOne = {loanname: "Mr X", acnumber:  "020000000000001", outstanding: "54000"},
    {loanname: "Mrs Y", acnumber: "020000000000087", outstanding: "87000"},
    {loanname: "Mr Z", acnumber:  "020000000000103", outstanding: "15000"},

let secondOne ={loanname: "David", acnumber: "020000000000091", outstanding: "11000"},
    {loanname: "James", acnumber: "020000000001291", outstanding: "4000"},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

First of all, check if there is `totalaccount` property exists or not. If `yes` then create a new array in the `acc` using the `push` method of `Array.prototype` If `totalaccount` property doesn't exists then just push the object in the last array of `acc`. You need to track the last array element index with `current`

```js
const data = [
  { loanname: "Mr X", acnumber: "020000000000001", outstanding: "54000" },
  { loanname: "Mrs Y", acnumber: "020000000000087", outstanding: "87000" },
  { loanname: "Mr Z", acnumber: "020000000000103", outstanding: "15000" },
  { totalaccount: "3", outstanding: "156000" },
  { loanname: "David", acnumber: "020000000000091", outstanding: "11000" },
  { loanname: "James", acnumber: "020000000001291", outstanding: "4000" },
  { totalaccount: "2", outstanding: "15000" },
];

let current = 0;
const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { totalaccount } = curr;
    if (totalaccount) {
      acc.push([]);
      ++current;
    } else {
      acc[current].push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
  },
  [[]]
);

const [first, second] = result;
console.log(first);
console.log(second);
console.log(result);
```

You can also achieve the same result without tracking the `current` as

```js
const data = [
  { loanname: "Mr X", acnumber: "020000000000001", outstanding: "54000" },
  { loanname: "Mrs Y", acnumber: "020000000000087", outstanding: "87000" },
  { loanname: "Mr Z", acnumber: "020000000000103", outstanding: "15000" },
  { totalaccount: "3", outstanding: "156000" },
  { loanname: "David", acnumber: "020000000000091", outstanding: "11000" },
  { loanname: "James", acnumber: "020000000001291", outstanding: "4000" },
  { totalaccount: "2", outstanding: "15000" },
];

const result = data.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => {
    const { totalaccount } = curr;
    if (totalaccount) {
      acc.push([]);
    } else {
      acc[acc.length - 1].push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
  },
  [[]]
);

console.log(result);
```

**If you want to accumulate into one object and want to create property dynamically**

```js
const data = [
  { loanname: "Mr X", acnumber: "020000000000001", outstanding: "54000" },
  { loanname: "Mrs Y", acnumber: "020000000000087", outstanding: "87000" },
  { loanname: "Mr Z", acnumber: "020000000000103", outstanding: "15000" },
  { totalaccount: "3", outstanding: "156000" },
  { loanname: "David", acnumber: "020000000000091", outstanding: "11000" },
  { loanname: "James", acnumber: "020000000001291", outstanding: "4000" },
  { totalaccount: "2", outstanding: "15000" },
];

const result = data.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => {
    const { totalaccount } = curr;
    if (totalaccount) {
      acc.push([]);
    } else {
      acc[acc.length - 1].push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
  },
  [[]]
);

const resultObj = {};
result.forEach((d, i) => {
  if (d.length) {
    resultObj[`collection${i + 1}`] = [...d];
  }
});
console.log(resultObj);
```

Comment: It returns all the account numbers. It doesn't split the numbers depending on "totalaccount". In my question I asked if I could convert the array into variables named "firstOne" and "secondOne". Because there are "totalaccount" two times, I would like the array to split into two parts.  If there are "totalaccount" 3 times, I would like the array to split into three parts and so on. How can I do that?

Comment: It will do that for you just check the result array...

Comment: @Rashel—you can't conditionally create arbitrary variables within a loop like *firstOne*, *secondOne*, etc. You can either create an array or an object that has properties with the required names and assign the results to them, see [*Dynamically Creating Variables for Loops*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645067/javascript-dynamically-creating-variables-for-loops?r=SearchResults&s=1|144.1670).

Comment: Since `result` will return an array of array so you can get the data with array indexes.

Comment: @decpk Your code works for me. I needed the result to split into multiple parts because they are different type of loans and I will need them separate for future calculation.

Comment: @Rashel Edited the code and accumulated the result into one object with dynamic property. Check it out...

Comment: @decpk Thanks for your help. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this logic (not tested completely, just an idea)

```js
const myArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (!data[i].totalaccount) continue;
    myArray.push([]);
    for (let x = i - data[i].totalaccount; x <= i - 1; x++) {
      myArray[myArray.length-1].push(data[x]);
    }
}
console.log(myArray);
```